# Get user's screen_name with twitter API

Tags: python, api, twitter

I've started working with the twitter API, and I'd like to know the fastest way to get the authenticated user screen_name.

Comment: are you using any libraries @Kenny ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using oauthtwitter, which uses oauth and simplejson, i think

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to complete oauthtwitter lib with more defs and use it with a twitter bot project

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm using the twitteroauth  (i assume that's what you mean) library in a project atm and if you're retrieving the user information like this:

```
$user_info = $twitteroauth->get('account/verify_credentials');
```

You can retrieve the user screen name with: `echo $user_info->screen_name;`

Comment: Its completely irrevelant to the question. How the heck is it possible that in python, php can be used?

Comment: So when I wrote this answer about 5 years ago i didn't notice that it was python related. After I realized my mistake, the answer was already marked as the best answer so it couldn't be deleted. yay.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way is to grab the [python-twitter library](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter) ( which provides an object and method for just about everything - also note - use the latest sources, don't fetch the zipped files) and use the `GetUser` method

```
>>> import twitter
>>> api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=conskey, consumer_secret=conssec, access_token_key=accstkn, >>> access_token_secret=accssec)
>>> usr = api.GetUser(11594372) # passing the user id here
>>> print usr.GetName()
Sathya
```